# Why does editing colors in Angular not work correctly?

Tags: javascript, angular, colors, hsl

Heyo, I'm trying to set colors for some inline SVG element programmatically but it doesn't really work.

My code has, for example:

```
baseColor: HSLColor = HSLColor.of(30, 40, 50); //ugly but good for experiments
strokeColor: HSLColor = HSLColor.of(0, 0, 60); //default value, gets replaced

...

ngOnInit() {
  this.strokeColor = {...this.baseColor, value: Math.max(0, this.baseColor.value - 40)};
}
```

```
<path d="..." style="{{'fill:' + this.baseColor + ';stroke:' + this.strokeColor + ';stroke-width:0.84px;'}}"/>
```

The resulting DOM element has a fill but NO stroke.
I've tried setting it via ngStyle, too. Doesn't work either.

My plan is to have the stroke color be a darker base color. For that, I thought I could just use the old attributes of the `baseColor` (hue, saturation, value) and override the `value` with a new one. If I remove the line in the onInit() method, a stroke will be visible (using the default color I set up above). The contents of `this.strokeColor` are virtually the same before onInit() and after, only with different values. Printing JSON.stringify(this.strokeColor) to console reveals as much. But it seems there is still some difference and I can't get my head around what it is.

Converting my frankenstein'ed stroke color to HSLColor with `as` doesn't work, either.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.strokeColor = {...this.baseColor, value: Math.max(0, this.baseColor.value - 40)} as HSLColor;
}
```

Using the following actually **works** but I'm just trying to figure out WHY:

```
this.strokeColor = HSLColor.of(this.baseColor.hue, this.baseColor.saturation, this.baseColor.value - 40);
```

Comment: In first instance (under `ngOnInit`) you create an object with `value` as one property. Check what `HSLColor.of` function actually returns. Btw `as HSLColor` only silences Typescript errors - warnings. It will not do the actual "convert" to that type.

Comment: @robert I don't get your first sentence. I create an object with all properties copied over from the original object, but then I override the value property. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Yes, correct. You created an object and overwrite a `value` property. `HSLColor.of` belongs to which lib? Does it return the same object with a `value` property?

Comment: @robert depends on what you mean by the same. The objects both have the same hue, saturation and value objects as well as the same type of those properties.